# $\sigma$-indepencene in affine multi-factor model for interest rate derivatives

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, bond

The model here is affine two-factor model for interest rates.

Let $p = p(r, \sigma)$ denote bond prices which take the usual exponential form.

Let $r$ have some $Q$ dynamics, and let $\sigma$ be the stochastic (!) volatility.

- Are there known conditions one can impose on the dynamics such that $p$ does not depend on $\sigma$?
- Given those conditions, would $\sigma$ still make  have its say in the determination of option prices (e.g., a call), and if so, why?

For the first, I am thinking something there may be some particular unspanned stochastic volatility model? For the second, I am not sure.

Comment: For your first question, I do not think that is possible. Even in the simple Ho-Lee model, the bond price depends on the volatility. See [this question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30995/pricing-interest-rate-swap-in-ho-lee-model/30997#30997) for details.